# How to plot curve instead of lines in the below figure?I am using Log scale in x axis.

Tags: graphing-functions

[image: How to plot curve instead of lines in the below figure?I am using Log scale in x axis.]

How to plot curve instead of lines in the below figure?I am using Log scale in x axis.

Comment: Use cosine interpolation instead of linear at each point.

Comment: Can you please tell me the syntax?

Comment: Check [this](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/). This has many more methods and syntax is provided for each of them.

Comment: Thanks.But,I couldnt find it,Can you please tell me your mailid so that I can mail the file?